# <data-list> for <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

On the input element, we can use `<data-list>` to define autocomplete for a quick choice for multiple input elements.  I have many select elements that I want to send on form with same `<option>`. Is there any tag that is similar to `<data-list>` to use in `<select>` tag?

```
<select name='table1'>
  <option value='a'>table a</option>
---------------------------------------
  <option value='zz'>table zz</option>
</select>
<select name='table2'>
  <option value='a'>table a</option>
---------------------------------------
  <option value='zz'>table zz</option>
</select>
<select name='table3'>
  <option value='a'>table a</option>
---------------------------------------
  <option value='zz'>table zz</option>
</select>
```

to be something like this

```
<select name='table1' list='table'></select>
<select name='table2' list='table'></select>
<select name='table3' list='table'></select>
<data-list>
  <option value='a'>table a</option>
---------------------------------------
  <option value='zz'>table zz</option>
<data-list>
```

Comment: `<datalist>` is for `<input>`, not for `<select>`. You could write some javascript that copies the element for you, if you want the same options on multiple elements.

Comment: i want to add some input option on every table that i have so i can't use multiple select